# A doubt regarding trigonometric functions and polynomials

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, solution-verification

I present a very flawed "proof" of a famous problem

Consider a polynomial function :

$a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\cdots$, With roots, $r_1,r_2,r_3,\cdots$

Now,

$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}}=\dfrac{-a_1}{a_0}$, And $\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i\cdot r_j}}=\dfrac{a_2}{a_0}$

$(\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}})^2=\dfrac{a_1^2}{a_0^2}$ And $(2\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i\cdot r_j}})=\dfrac{2a_2}{a_0}$

$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i^2}}=(\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}})^2-(2\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i\cdot r_j}})$

Consider $\cos(x)$ as the polynomial to get:

$a_1=0, a_2=\dfrac{-1}{2}, a_0=1 $

So, $\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i^2}}=0-2\dfrac{-1}{2}=1$

Now the roots of $\cos(x)-0$ are always real: $\dfrac{\pi}{2},\dfrac{-\pi}{2},\dfrac{3\pi}{2}\dfrac{-3\pi}{2},\dfrac{5\pi}{2},\dfrac{-5\pi}{2}+,\cdots$

$\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i^2}}=1=2(\dfrac{4}{1^2\pi^2}+\dfrac{4}{3^2\pi^2}+\dfrac{4}{5^2\pi^2}+\dfrac{4}{7^2\pi^2}+\cdots)$

Therefore $\dfrac{\pi^2}{8}=\dfrac{1}{1^2}+\dfrac{1}{3^2}+\dfrac{1}{5^2}+\dfrac{1}{7^2}+\cdots$

Why does my wrong assumption considering cosine as a polynomial work in this case? Why does the function follow polynomial properties if it isn't actually a polynomial?

What would I need to prove additionally in order to prove this "proof" legit or faulty?

Comment: I believe this argument is essentially due to Euler so it has a very fine pedigree in mathematics. Check out the Weierstrass factorization theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_factorization_theorem

Comment: Not only that $\cos$ is not a polynomial, $\sum{\frac{1}{r_i}}$ also diverges.

Comment: @MartinR I believe $\sum{\dfrac{1}{r_i}}=0$ since cosine lacks an $x^1$ coefficient. Additionally  the summation is just, $\dfrac {2}{\pi}-\dfrac{2}{\pi}+\cdots=0$ at least it seems that way :)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks a lot, I've read about this theorem but there aren't any good resources that go into detail and even if they do, they go past the high school level, something I'm not familiar with :|

Comment: It's just not a high school level question you've asked, unfortunately. I'm not very familiar with the details but basically this argument gets lucky; the Weierstrass factorization in this case happens to be exactly what you'd expect by working as naively as possible and pretending that $\cos x$ is a polynomial (at least if you pair up each root with its negative). In general this isn't true (e.g. it fails badly for $e^x$ which has no roots) and the Weierstrass factorization theorem tells you what happens in general.